# How to return array of NSObject based on many Core Data entities?

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9

I have this code below implemented in AppDelegate.swift:

```
func persistentStoreEnsemble(ensemble: CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble, globalIdentifiersForManagedObjects objects: [NSManagedObject]) -> [NSObject] {
    let entities = objects as! [Category]
    return entities.map {$0.uniqueIdentifier}
}
```

This project uses Core Data and 'Category' is one Entity form my model.

Problem is the function only works with the ‘Category’ entity, but my project has Subcategory, Item, Note and Recover as other entities. So, how could I code for that method work with all Entities and return the value according to the Entity it receives?

So, how can I do that?

Comment: So why not just return `objects`?

Comment: Well, actually I don´t how to answer you because that function is from a framework, so I think it should return an array as NSObject

Comment: But `[NSManagedObject]` (the type of `objects`) is also `[NSObject]`. `NSManagedObject` inherits from `NSObject`. You should be able to just do `return objects`.

Comment: Ok, then how would the code be using your suggestion for all other entities?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to use this `objects` array for? Your question just states you want to return `objects`. Probably you want to expand it to explain your actual problem.

Comment: I edited the question to better explain what´s the problem and what I want.

Comment: What exact type is the property `uniqueIdentifier`?

Comment: @vadian String type

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working by using this code:

```
func persistentStoreEnsemble(ensemble: CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble, globalIdentifiersForManagedObjects objects: [NSManagedObject]) -> [NSObject] {

    var array = [NSObject]()

    for object in objects {
        let value: NSObject? = object.valueForKeyPath("uniqueIdentifier") as? NSObject
        array.append(value!)
    }

    return array

}
```

Comment: This is a dynamic obj-c approach to solving the problem